# How to call integrate simple dialog and QnA maker dialog in a single bot?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

First I've to take phone no as a user input, than I need to call qnadialog till user quits. Following is my code:

```
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    private string phoneNo;
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result;

        await this.SendWelcomeMessageAsync(context);
    }
    private async Task SendWelcomeMessageAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNo))
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Hi, I'm Anna. Let's get started.");
            context.Call(new PhoneNoDialog(), this.PhoneNoDialogResumeAfter);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Forward(new SimpleQnADialog(), ResumeAfterSimpleQnADialog, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);                
        }
    }
    private async Task PhoneNoDialogResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
            this.phoneNo = await result;
            await context.PostAsync($"Thank you for the information. How can I help you?");
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterSimpleQnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
            context.Done<object>(null);            
    }
}
```

PhoneNoDialog.cs

```
public class PhoneNoDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    private int attempts = 3;

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Please enter your phone no");

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        if ((message.Text != null) && (message.Text.Trim().Length > 0))
        {
            context.Done(message.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            --attempts;
            if (attempts > 0)
            {
                await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry, I don't understand your reply. What is your phone no?");
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail(new TooManyAttemptsException("Message was not a string or was an empty string."));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleQnADialog.cs

```
[QnAMaker("subkey", "kbid")]
public class SimpleQnADialog : QnAMakerDialog
{

}
```

Everything works fine if I create independent bot with QnAmaker but if I call the context in above mentioned way, than it doesn't work as expected. I am not sure where I'm going wrong with this. And also, many a times bot emulator gives unexpected exceptions.

Comment: I try to reproduce the issue based on the code you provided, it works on my side. Please check if it forwards to your `SimpleQnADialog` and if it makes request to your QnA Maker service?

Comment: Can you add a demo (capture of emulator?) of the issue?

Comment: @NicolasR :Please go through the trail log from bot emulator for one such errors that I get arbitrarily:  [19:35:19] <- POST 200 setPrivateConversationData 
[19:35:20] <- POST 200 setConversationData 
[19:35:20] <- POST 200 setUserData 
[19:35:21] -> POST 200 [message] how to check status? 
[19:35:31] -> POST 500 [message] what not to do? 
[19:35:44] -> POST 500 [message] how to get things done? 
[19:35:56] -> POST 500 [message] hello

POST 500 messages are all errors. And it sometimes throws exceptions like "Empty stack" or "An error occured while sending the request"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to complete your `RootDialog` after the QnA got a reply when you implement this:

```
private async Task ResumeAfterSimpleQnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
        context.Done<object>(null);            
}
```

In fact, the QnAMakerDialog is completing once it has tried to answer, as you can see on its sources [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L203).

If you want to loop on questions, you should call again the wait:

```
private async Task ResumeAfterSimpleQnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```